# Scatter plot lines for a linear model using stat_smooth

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics

My question is rather basic, I'm sorry if I'm missing something obvious..

Anyway, with the following code:

```
library(gcookbook)
library(ggplot2)

x <- ggplot(heightweight, aes(x = ageYear, y = heightIn))+
geom_point()+
stat_smooth(method = lm, level = 0.95)

x
```

I get the plot:

[image: scatter]

The chart displays nicely, but with a 95% confidence level, why are there so many spots out of the grey boundary?

Comment: You are looking at confidence intervals not prediction intervals (see predict.lm) so this is the confidence interval of the regression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The se provided by geom_smooth is standard error of the prediction, and the confidence interval you are seeing is +/- 1.96*se of the prediction, see below on how it can be calculated:

```
fit = lm(heightIn ~ ageYear,data=heightweight)
newdata = data.frame(ageYear=seq(min(heightweight$ageYear),
max(heightweight$ageYear),by=0.1))
pred = predict(fit,newdata,se=TRUE)
newdata$heightIn = pred$fit
newdata$se = pred$se.fit

ggplot(heightweight, aes(x = ageYear, y = heightIn))+
geom_point()+
geom_line(data=newdata,col="cadetblue")+
geom_ribbon(data=newdata,aes(ymin=heightIn-1.96*se,ymax=heightIn+1.96*se),
alpha=0.2,fill="cadetblue")
```

[image]

If you want to have a 95% confidence interval of your data, you can try:

```
ggplot(heightweight, aes(x = ageYear, y = heightIn))+
     geom_point()+
     geom_quantile(quantiles=c(0.05,0.5,0.95))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @StupidWolf for the explanation, I'll dig into it and provide you with feedback

Comment: Ok, I got it. I just don't understand how se is being calculated. For example, according to the model, the prediction of height for the youngest age (11.58) is 57.68034. How is the se returning 0.339 for that age?

Comment: if you briefly look at the formula on this page, https://lbelzile.github.io/lineaRmodels/confidence-and-prediction-intervals.html, there is a part s^2 which is the estimated variance.. as your samples increase, your s^2 will get smaller

Comment: in this situation you have a lot of observations, n>200, hence the error is small. I understand it is counterintuitive, but be in mind, what you are inferring is the mean at this position and how off you can potentially be.. it does not tell you spread the data can be

Comment: you can also try fitting it with smaller subsets of the data, and you can see the confidence interval increases